# How to digitally sign every page of an PDF using itext 7

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

Below is my code

```cs
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SourcePdfFile);

string DestPdfFileName = Path.Combine(DestPdfFolder, "test1.pdf");
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileStream(DestPdfFileName, FileMode.Create), new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());

signer.SetFieldName("SignField1");

PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
appearance.SetReason("Page 1 sign")
    .SetLocation("blore")
    .SetPageRect(new Rectangle(400, 90, 540, 40))
    .SetPageNumber(1);
signer.SetFieldName("SignField2");

IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);

signer.SignDetached(pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

How can I make the "SetPageNumber" property of PdfSignatureAppearance Class dynamic?

I have tried to add multiple object of "PdfSignatureAppearance" Class, but only the last one is working.

Note: Is there a process to do this or do I have to open the pdf every time for signing?

Comment: *"How to digitally sign every page of an PDF"* - You always sign the full document, i.e. every page, not only a single page. `SetPageNumber` merely allows you to select on which page (if any) a visual in-document representation of the signature shall be created.

Comment: But I want to have the visual representation multiple times in the document. How can I do that?

Comment: Strictly speaking that is not desired by the spec authors and, therefore, forbidden. Some approaches used to be accepted by Adobe Reader, but that may change any time.